# как поменять версию NPM на старую

Tags: reactjs, npm

Начал осваивать REACT. Такая проблема, запускаю в командной строке, чтобы создать проект REACT:
create-react-app MyAppName
получаю ошибку:

```
 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:668:27)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:52:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
```

прочитал вариант с npx, 
npx create-react-app myAppName
ошибка
npx: installed 1 in 12.735s
The "path" argument must be of type string
C:\Users\Ustas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
C:\Users\Ustas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\package.json: Unexpected string in JSON at position 520

прочитал, что нужно NPM версии 4.... , из-за этого проблема. У меня версия NPM 5.6.0

Как установить старую версию, и поможет ли ? Как-то глупо. Может кто подскажет как создать болванку REACT без танца с бубном ? Или откатить NPM до версии 4...

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо установить NVM (Node Version Manager) - это скрипт который позволяет управлять версиями Node. С помощью него вы сможете переключатся между разными версиями Node.

https://github.com/creationix/nvm